# fcntl substitute on Windows

Tags: python, windows, linux

I received a Python project (which happens to be a Django project, if that matters,) that uses the `fcntl` module from the standard library, which seems to be available only on Linux. When I try to run it on my Windows machine, it stops with an `ImportError`, because this module does not exist here.

Is there any way for me to make a small change in the program to make it work on Windows?

Comment: What specifically is the code trying to do with fcntl?  fcntl() does many different things.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The substitute of `fcntl` on windows are `win32api` calls. The usage is completely different. It is not some switch you can just flip.

In other words, porting a `fcntl`-heavy-user module to windows is not trivial. It requires you to analyze what exactly each `fcntl` call does and then find the equivalent `win32api` code, if any.

There's also the possibility that some code using `fcntl` has no windows equivalent, which would require you to change the module api and maybe the structure/paradigm of the program using the module you're porting.

If you provide more details about the `fcntl` calls people can find windows equivalents.

Comment: Do you have information on whether using a single lock file for synchronization of other files is safe to do on Windows? We seem to still get race conditions after doing this despite the lock file locking and unlocking in an atomic manner just fine. It's like unlocking it does not create a happens-before guarantee for the other files we wrote while the lock was held.

Comment: @Zyl the answer you're commenting on doesn't have anything to do with locks at all, it explains about `fcntl`/`win32api` calls, which can be used to do almost anything; I wouldn't believe anything is safe on windows; I suggest asking another question instead of commenting

Answer (score 48):

The fcntl module is just used for locking the pinning file, so assuming you don't try multiple access, this can be an acceptable workaround.  Place this module in your `sys.path`, and it should just work as the official fcntl module.

Try using [this module](https://community.cisco.com/kxiwq67737/attachments/kxiwq67737/jive-disc-developer-archive/8642/1/fcntl.py.zip) ([source](https://community.cisco.com/t5/jive-developer-archive/no-module-named-fcntl/td-p/3607329)) for development/testing purposes only in windows.

```
def fcntl(fd, op, arg=0):
    return 0
        
def ioctl(fd, op, arg=0, mutable_flag=True):
    if mutable_flag:
        return 0
    else:
        return ""
    
def flock(fd, op):
    return
        
def lockf(fd, operation, length=0, start=0, whence=0):
    return
```

Of course, then you need to place the `fcntl.py` module in your `site-packages` directory for the Python interpreter that you want to use. For example, `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fcntl\`. This is where my `site-packages` live. Check [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-find-the-location-of-my-Python-site-packages-directory) to find where yours is located.

Comment: This is such a hack; but it's what I needed.  :)

Comment: Added numeric constants.

Comment: How about fcntl.F_GETFD and fcntl.F_SETFD

Comment: I know this is an old post but I found it useful in the last couple of days. Some variables were missing, I updated the code in the original message.

Comment: link appears to be broken

Comment: How to add this to sys.path? I tried adding this on the same folder as my python script but it didnt work

Comment: @luthfianto you need to place it in your `site-packages` directory for the Python interpreter that you want to use. For example, `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\fcntl`. This is where my `site-packages` live. Check [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-find-the-location-of-my-Python-site-packages-directory#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20the%20location%20of%20Python%20site-packages,run%20the%20following%20code%20in%20your%20shell%20%E2%88%92) to find yours.

Comment: Requiring a cisco login to view links makes this not a great SO answer, imo. I'd suggest hosting somewhere more friendly random SO users like gitlab or github, for instance.

Answer (score 17):

Although this does not help you right away, there is an alternative that can work with both Unix (fcntl) and Windows (win32 api calls), called: **portalocker**

It describes itself as a cross-platform (posix/nt) API for flock-style file locking for Python. It basically maps fcntl to win32 api calls.

The original code at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65203/ can now be installed as a separate package - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/portalocker

Comment: `fcntl` does a lot more things than lock files.