# how i process this python file on windows?

Tags: android, python, linux, windows

The python file name is orientationplot.py 
This file is very easy to find by google.
This python script is used for visualizing the behavior of the WindowOrientationListener in android. 
but it is write for linux.
I want to use it in windows.
but there is a error, how can I make this file run in windows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\perftool\orientationplot\orientationplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import fcntl
ImportError: No module named fcntl
fcntl.fcntl(stream, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Comment: `fcntl` is a Unix utility. If you want to port the script to Windows, you'll have to work out what Unix functionality it's using and rewrite that in terms of Windows. It' s not magically going to work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows.

Comment: I see,can this "    fcntl.fcntl(stream, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)" replace by some words, so it can run in windows.

Comment: @user1966742 See my answer for how you might implement this in Windows.

Comment: I never use python before ,also lack of socket communicate knowledge.It's hard for me.

Comment: @user1966742 You have two options then. 1) Learn about those things, maybe asking thoughtful questions here when you get stuck. 2) Hiring someone to do it. This is not a trivial task.

Comment: I have some idea，I think I can make it , I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You definitely cannot simply rewrite this program for Windows. It makes heavy use of the `fcntl` module. If you aren't aware, [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) is a system call on Linux that manipulates file descriptors.

```
fcntl.fcntl(stream, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

nosklo wrote in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422436/1901658):

> The substitute of `fcntl` on windows are `win32api` calls. The usage is completely different. It is not some switch you can just flip.

I do want to point out, though, that with some research this is probably possible. You need to figure out how to set the file descriptor flags of a stream in Windows (that is, the stream's permissions and other flags specified by the [open() system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)), and setting `os.O_NONBLOCK`. I found some more information on the [Winsock website](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html):

> The Unix fcntl() call has no direct equivalent under Winsock. Where
>   necessary, similar functionality exists in Winsock’s ioctlsocket()
>   call. For example, the equivalent of using Unix’s fcntl() to set a
>   socket’s O_NONBLOCK flag is setting the FIONBIO flag with Winsock’s
>   ioctlsocket().