# what is the ipython notebook "Terminals" menu option

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am running ipython notebook on my OSX machine and/or my ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I am using ipython 3.0.0, and ipython (jupyter) notebooks.

When I start an ipython notebook, under New there is a terminal option, but it's unavailable for me.
I haven't been able to find any documentation on this feature, how to activate it or what it does.
The `ipython notebook --help` command doesn't mention it and I haven't found anything in the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/index.html) either.
I haven't discovered the special keywords to search google for to get any information either.

What does this feature do? How do I activate it? Is there any documentation on this available?

[image]

Comment: I only get "New Notebook" button in the upper-right corner of the ipython-notebooks web interface. What set of IPython/Jupiter addons are you using? AFAICS, there's no separate "jupiter notebook", jupiter extends ipython's functionality.

Comment: Are you using ipython 3.0.0?

Comment: Nope! Updating fixed that.

Comment: I hate asking "what does this do?" questions on SO, but I cannot find a shred of documentation on this anywhere....

Comment: For OSS, there's always the most detailed documentation possible called "source code" ;-)

Comment: `pip install terminado`  to get an in browser terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code in `Lib/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py` responsible for this item (located the file by searching the source for "Terminals" case-sensitively):

```py
def init_terminals(self):
    try:
        from .terminal import initialize
        initialize(self.web_app)
        self.web_app.settings['terminals_available'] = True
    except ImportError as e:
        log = self.log.debug if sys.platform == 'win32' else self.log.warn
        log("Terminals not available (error was %s)", e)
```

As you can see, there should be a message in the console log specifying what went wrong (you may need to increase log verbosity with `ipython notebook --log-level=<level>` to see it). In my case, it said:

> Terminals not available (error was No module named fcntl)

The `html.terminal` module that is being imported appears to provide a web-based IPython interactive console.

Comment: what is the pip package for fcntl for windows?

Comment: @Gomes None, `fcntl` API is UNIX-specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows .

Comment: If unclear from @ivan_pozdeev comment, the browser terminal feature is not available from Windows. See [Jupyter/notebook issue #172](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/172).

Answer (score 14):

IPython/Jupyter appears to support browser-based interactive terminal sessions. This is enabled on my machine by installing the `terminado` package with `pip` or `conda`. This fixes the "Terminals Unavailable" message on the drop-down, and lets me start up a (bash) terminal session in a new tab.

See this commit:
[IPython on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/515b791b6b3e0def1a74b816316356669f52c7f6)

Comment: Installed jupyter and terminado using pip, but still can't access terminals (Win).

Comment: Exactly the same with me - annaconda distribution used - although I used pip for the terminado (as no conda install available)

Comment: @CzarekTomczak did you find an answer?

Comment: ignore me - looks like because I'm using windows this feature is not available

Comment: @whytheq Terminals are not supported on Windows

Comment: It will work on windows if you happen to have a msys2/cygwin environment with minimum python installed. and activate your usual virtual env, reinstall and launch notebook/jupyterlab from there.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Windows terminals with terminado dependency was added in Jupyter 5.3.0:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3087

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's jupyter notebook 5.3.0, not jupyter. the two versions is not the same thing. 
- `jupyter --version`
- `jupyter notebook --version`

I ever suffered from this.