# Difference between Procfile and Procfile.Windows in heroku servers

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm learning how to deploy a **Django** project with **Heroku**.

And I notice two files in this repository (git from tutorial): https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started

The file **Procfile**, I do understand what's for. However, the file **Procfile.windows** is something that I quite not understand.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just starting and running into the same issue.
I believe that some django packages e.g. gunicorn [don't work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562309/11236).

That's why the Heroku example app comes pre-packed with a separate "Procfile.windows" that does not use gunicorn.

To use it, do

```
heroku local -f Procfile.windows
```

... now just to find out how to make it the default.

Comment: Indeed. God, django is such a pain to configure. I'm thinking of dropping it in favor of some simpler micro-server.

Comment: Believe me , I use web sphere in my job and it's a pain  greater. I miss old days with php and Apache servers. No frameworks hehhehe thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Procfile.windows` is the file for Windows machine to run the application locally.  Follow the steps below and try it out yourself:

1. Create a file called **`Procfile.windows`** at the same level where `manage.py` resides.
2. Add this inside the file: `web: python manage.py runserver`
3. Run this in your cmd: `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` or `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`

Also, you can follow the steps from the official Heroku website (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally).  This is probably the better way to do it in my opinion.