# How to create a config file and tell Gunicorn to use it?

Tags: python, gunicorn

my app was running great but then I changed some things and now it can sometimes 'think' for more then 30 seconds before getting back to me. The problem is that Gunicorn times-out after 30 seconds:

```
[2016-03-28 18:25:52 +0000] [3] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8)
2016-03-28T18:25:52.625220+00:00 app[web.1]:
[2016-03-28 18:25:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
```

Now, I did some research and I know that I need to create a config file for Gunicorn and put a command to override Gunicorn's timeout default, like this:
`TIMEOUT=120`
But how do I do that? I mean, how do I tell Gunicorn to look in, for example, gunicorn_config.txt and respect the laws I create for it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Config files can be written as an INI file or as a Python file. If you're using a Python file (which is what I'd recommend), put this inside it:

```
timeout = 120
```

Or, if you want to use an INI file:

```
[server:main]
timeout = 120
```

Then, when you run Gunicorn, add a `-c` option to tell Gunicorn where your config file is, like this:

```
gunicorn -c config.py ...
```

See [this file](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py) for a list of options that you can use in your config file.

---

For your example, you don't need a config file at all. Simply run Gunicorn with the `--timeout` option:

```
gunicorn --timeout 120 ...
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I tried the simple solution `gunicorn --timeout 120` but it threw me this error `ImportError: No module named 'fcntl'` which, after some research, I discovered is because Gunicorn doesn't run on windows..? Do you know anything about that? Is their a way around it?

Comment: @KristiferSzabo `fcntl` is a tool which is able to set file flags; it's Linux only which is why you get an `ImportError`. It [doesn't look like it's easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows) to get around that, and most people seem to recommend using a Linux VM instead.

Comment: @KristiferSzabo Full Windows support appears to be planned, and with comments on [this GitHub issue from 3 days ago](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524) it looks like a Windows version may be in development.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. There was only a few cases in which the app would trigger the timeout, ill just avoid those cases from now on. Thanks again

Comment: @AaronChristiansen I am using Python to build a line-bot right now on windows. I tried to put [server:main] timeout = 120 in ini file which store token and secret but still not working. Would you like to give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: Changed in version 19.4: Loading the config from a Python module requires the `python:` prefix. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#settings