# dogpile.cache 'No module named fcntl' error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dogpile.cache

I'm using Python 2.7 with SQLAlchemy. 
I'm trying to see if I can use Dogpile.Cache.
I've installed dogpile cache using

```
pip install dogpile.cache
```

but when I try to run the example given by SQLAlchemy ([helloworld.py](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.dogpile_caching))
I keep getting `ImportError: No module named fcntl`. I thought the newest Dogpile.Cache resolved the windows issue...

Could someone please help?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Ok, the example is creating the database and cache. But when it is trying to load data using `FromCache` it is giving me an error.

`people = Session.query(Person).options(FromCache("default")).all()`

Here is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\JKIM\Downloads\DogpileCacheTest\examples\dogpile_caching\helloworld.py", line 13, in <module>
    people = Session.query(Person).options(FromCache("default")).all()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2613, in all
  File "examples\caching_query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    return self.get_value(createfunc=lambda: list(Query.__iter__(self)))
  File "examples\caching_query.py", line 108, in get_value
    expiration_time=expiration_time
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\region.py", line 657, in get_or_create
    async_creator) as value:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\lock.py", line 154, in __enter__
    return self._enter()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\lock.py", line 87, in _enter
    value = value_fn()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\region.py", line 610, in get_value
    value = self.backend.get(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 220, in get
    with self._dbm_file(False) as dbm:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 212, in _dbm_file
    with self._use_rw_lock(write):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 207, in _use_rw_lock
    with self._rw_lock.read():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 327, in read
    self.acquire_read_lock(True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 408, in acquire_read_lock
    return self._acquire(wait, os.O_RDONLY, self._module.LOCK_SH)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\util\langhelpers.py", line 63, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dogpile\cache\backends\file.py", line 400, in _module
    import fcntl
ImportError: No module named fcntl
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: The python module `fcntl` is a Unix only module.  You can't use software that employs python modules with Unix only features.

Comment: Yes, I found this ticket in bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache/issues/44/cross-platform-file-caching) and was resolved. The newest version I installed was 0.6.1 and the issue was supposed to be resolved but seems like I cannot get it to work.

Comment: My reading of that issue is that a fix was NOT going to be added: *Windows just doesn't have a single, widely accepted approach for this kind of thing and I have no interest in endorsing one of them.*

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I guess I'll try Dutchreaper123's portalocker method.

Comment: Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows

Comment: Ah, thank you. It's not just a simple issue...