# Heroku returns "ImportError: No module named fcntl on window"

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, heroku, facebook-chatbot

I'm setting app on Heroku. I do in instruction like so:

[Image](http://prntscr.com/gilj7r)

In error 1, I code in Notepad and run it in command:

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
     r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/418')
     print(r.text)
     return HttpResponse('<pre>' + r.text + '</pre>')



def db(request):

    greeting = Greeting()
    greeting.save()

    greetings = Greeting.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'db.html', {'greetings': greetings})
```

But it dont run like instruction

My command appeard [that](http://prntscr.com/gilllp) so i dont know what can I should do.

I was try like [Stack help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows)

Comment: Your first error relates to seemingly not having Django installed. You should post your code and errors as text not as images.

Comment: @asongtoruin oh im so sorry, my fault. can you see that again and help me plz!

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if your question is still on, but I'm digging into heroku right now, too and I have a solution for you.
The fcntl module is a standard library available... on Linux only! You won't find it under Windows environment, which you are apparently using (hint: Notepad mentioned ;)

But no worries, just follow the official tutorial's previous lesson and invoke the local heroku server like:

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

This should start your local heroku server no problem, under:
http://localhost:5000

Hope that helps!

P.S. Don't run views.py on its own like that. The tutorial strictly says to do it under the virtual environment, then it works, like planned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is correct. Please install requests on your (master) as follows:

1. (python-getting-started) `Ja ~/python-getting-started` (master) `pipenv install requests`
2. then run `heroku local`