# Django Deployment on Heroku with Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, heroku, devops

After successfully deploying to Heroku, whenever i want to access the page i get "Application Error". Looking through my Heroku log, error below is what I get regularly.

```
2020-07-10T15:03:39.152131+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 181, in init_signals
2020-07-10T15:03:39.152372+00:00 app[web.1]: util.set_non_blocking(p)
2020-07-10T15:03:39.152403+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 253, in set_non_blocking
2020-07-10T15:03:39.152670+00:00 app[web.1]: flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK
2020-07-10T15:03:39.152717+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: module 'fcntl' has no attribute 'fcntl'
```

Comment: Did you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213098/3523510 ?

Comment: Yes i did, running it locally and still getting the same error!