# Error with "mlflow ui" when trying to run it on MS Windows

Tags: python, windows, fcntl, mlflow

When I run `mlflow ui` the following error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\gunicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 9, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\cli.py", line 131, in ui
    mlflow.server._run_server(file_store, file_store, host, port, 1)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\server\__init__.py", line 48, in _run_server
    env=env_map, stream_output=True)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 38, in exec_cmd
    raise ShellCommandException("Non-zero exitcode: %s" % (exit_code))
mlflow.utils.process.ShellCommandException: Non-zero exitcode: 1
```

I used anaconda + python 3.6.5 and I installed git and set path with `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

I installed `mlflow` whit `pip install mlflow` and its version is 0.2.1.

I set a variable with name `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` and value `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` in Environment Variables.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You might be hitting the following issue related to `fcntl`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422436/236007

Comment: And `fcntl` problem might be one of the reasons why they wrote "Note 2: We do not currently support running MLflow on Windows. Despite this, we would appreciate any contributions to make MLflow work better on Windows." at https://github.com/databricks/mlflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mlflow documentation](https://github.com/databricks/mlflow) already says that

> Note 2: We **do not currently support running MLflow on Windows**.
>   Despite this, we would appreciate any contributions to make MLflow
>   work better on Windows.

You're hitting `fcntl` problem: it's not available on MS Windows platform because it's a "wrapper" around the [fcntl function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) that's available on POSIX-compatible systems. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422436/236007 for more details.)

Solving this requires modifying the source code of mlflow accordingly.

Comment: [Here](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/06/06/announcing-the-mlflow-1-0-release.html) in 5th para of "what's new", they claim Windows is now compatible but still we have the same issue.

Comment: Note that the mentioned documentaion page is of an archived beta version fork from https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow.

Answer (score 3):

firstly Uninstall 'mlflow' and 'waitress', then again install 'mlflow' .Now try it works

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, these steps work for me:

- pip uninstall mlflow
- pip -m virtualenv env-name
- pip install conda
- pip install mlflow
- mlflow ui --> INFO:waitress:Serving on http://127.0.0.1:5000