# having trouble running fcntl and flock in windows Code::Blocks

Tags: c, linux, windows, flock, fcntl

I have been trying to make a file locking program in windows using Code::Blocks. With to many errors popping in my original code, I decided to copy it from a youtube tutorial video on fcntl. Even though I copied the exact same code from yt, it's still throwing a lot of errors in the terminal. How can I run fcntl code in windows machine?

Here is the code:

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
char* file = argv[1];
int fd;

struct flock lock;

printf("I am opening the file %s\n",file);
fd = open(file, O_WRONLY);
printf("I am locking the file buddy!\n");

memset(&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
lock.l_type = F_WRLOCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);
printf("I locked the file, press to unlock\n");

getchar();

printf("Releasing lock\n");

lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);

close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
error: storage size of lock isn't known
error: F_WRLOCK undeclared, first use in this function(same for F_SETLWK and F_UNLCK)
also a warning, implicit declaration of function fcntl.
```

Do I have to use some other softwares to run the program? Please help in as much detail as possible, Thank you.

Comment: `fcntl` is a posix function, and not on windows.  This is probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422368/fcntl-substitute-on-windows.

Comment: is there any program or something I can download to test this ?

Comment: Use Win32 syscalls instead. `CreateFile()` lets you control file access.