# Multiple python scripts sending messages to a single central script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, interprocess

I have a number of scripts written in Python 2.6 that can be run arbitrarily. I would like to have a single central script that collects the output and displays it in a single log.

Ideally it would satisfy these requirements:

- Every script sends its messages to the same "receiver" for display.
- If the receiver is not running when the first script tries to send a message, it is started.
- The receiver can also be launched and ended manually. (Though if ended, it will restart if another script tries to send a message.)
- The scripts can be run in any order, even simultaneously.
- Runs on **Windows**. Multiplatform is better, but at least it needs to work on Windows.

I've come across some hints:

- `os.pipe()`
- `multiprocess`
- [Occupying a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program)
- `mutex`
- [`logging.handlers.SocketHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) (thanks @Dan Head)

From those pieces, I think I could cobble something together. Just wondering if there is an obviously 'right' way of doing this, or if I could learn from anyone's mistakes.

Comment: Have you looked at logging.handlers.SocketHandler: http://docs.python.org/library/logging#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network ? It does at least part of what you describe for you and is part of the standard library.

Comment: @Dan That looks quite useful, you should write it up as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd consider using [`logging.handlers.SocketHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) for the message passing parts of this, it sounds like you have a logging type use case in mind already.

The standard libraries logging facilities are very flexible and configuration driven so you should be able to adapt them to your requirements.

This doesn't handle the automatic restarting part of your question.  For UNIX you'd probably just use pid files and `os.kill(pid, 0)` to check if it's running, but I don't know what their equivalents in the Windows world would be.

Comment: This definitely seems like *exactly* what I want for message sending. Thanks. :)  It does, however, leave the question of automatic restarting. I'll probably just start a new question more focused on that.

Comment: I don't know too much about these things on Windows, `inetd` is the sort of thing you'd use in old school UNIX land.  Maybe there's a Windows equivalent?

Comment: You _could_ just restart the receiver script from within the other scripts if they fail to connect to the port you've specified...

Comment: Yes... the page is a bit sparse on the exceptions that Logging raises, but that should actually be pretty straightforward. The receiver should also choke if a second one tries to listen on that port, so I think this will work wonderful. :)

Answer (score 1):

I built a server to use a Windows named pipe, using the following key code:

```
    def run( self ):
        # This is the main server loop for the Win32 platform
        import win32pipe
        import win32file
        self.pipeHandle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
            '\\\\.\\pipe\\myapp_requests',
            win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE |
            win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_BYTE |
            win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
            1,
            4096,
            4096,
            10000,
            None)
        if self.pipeHandle == win32file.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
            print 'Failed to create named pipe %s!' % self.pipeName
            print 'Exiting...'
            sys.exit(1)
        while True:
            # Open file connection
            win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe( self.pipeHandle )

            # Run the main message loop until it exits, usually because
            # of a loss of communication on the pipe
            try:
                self.messageLoop()
            except ServerKillSignal:
                break

            # Return the pipes to their disconnected condition and try again
            try: win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe( self.pipeHandle )
            except: pass
        win32file.CloseHandle( self.pipeHandle )
        print "Exiting server"
```

The method `messageLoop()` reads data from the pipe, using `win32file.ReadFile()`, until win32file.error is thrown.  Then it exits, allowing run() to restart it.

In my implementation, the users were not likely to have administrator access, so this could not be started as a system service.  Instead, I coded the client to check for the existence of the pipe at '\.\pipe\pyccf_requests'.  If it doesn't exist, then the client starts a new server process.

Comment: This looks useful. Is this the library you are using? http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/

Comment: Yes, that's it.  It is included as part of the ActiveState python distribution, which is what I was building against:

http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Dan Head's answer is exactly what you want.

Item #2, "If the receiver is not running when the first script tries to send a message, it is started", probably won't work.  Something has to be running to receive a message.  I suggest writing a demon process which starts on bootup, and tell Windows to restart it if it dies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm weighing this against other suggestions of having the receiver occupy a port/pipe, and spawning it if it's not found. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That solution is fine. I'd suggest that might have too much "smarts" in a single application.  Have a server, a client, and a script which restarts a demon if it crashes.  The restarter could work on any server.  In this way each piece is simpler and thus more reliable.