# Can a Python script identify itself in memory at runtime?

Tags: python, locking, singleton

I am looking for methods other than file locking to make sure that only one instance of a  Python script is being run at the same time.

Is there a way to identify a currently running script in memory? Perhaps by setting a flag of some kind that other instances can read so they can exit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: single instance of program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program)

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on Linux, /dev/shm is a tmpfs partition on most distros.
This means that any files stored there only exist in memory and are not written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Windows, use a Mutex.  You can use ctypes to call the Win32 APIs: CreateMutex, WaitForSingleObject, and ReleaseMutex.