# Python prevent multiple-instances / tkinter instance

Tags: python, tkinter, instance, multiple-instances

Python 3.10 (OS Windows 10, 64 bit)

Hi,

I compiled my Python tkinter code. When
I run the *.exe twice there are two tkinter main
windows (the same as when I'd
run the windows notepad.exe twice).

But I want to prevent the tkinter .exe can be
started twice. Can I do something so that tkinter
can be started only one time no matter
whether I click tkinter.exe on the
windows desktop a dozen times .

Comment: Do you have your code in a `main()` function? Do you care for cross platform compatibility?

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/make-sure-only-a-single-instance-of-a-program-is-running/54746426#54746426)

Comment: I mean at least one is is to have a file and when the program starts it checks that file, if nothing is there, it starts and writes to the file something, if something is there (the text that would be written if there was nothing), then it doesn't start, it immediately just exits and when you close the window (protocol 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW'), it clears that file

Comment: @Thingamabobs it just has to work in windows (not in other platforms)

Comment: @SamuelKazeem Thanks, your answer works for windows10: import win32event
import win32api
import sys
from winerror import ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
mutex = win32event.CreateMutex(None, False, 'name')
last_error = win32api.GetLastError()
if last_error == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
sys.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

**@SamuelKazeem -Thanks. Your answer works for Windows10 :**

```
import win32event
import win32api
import sys
from winerror import ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
mutex = win32event.CreateMutex(None, False, 'name')
last_error = win32api.GetLastError()
if last_error == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
   sys.exit(0)

import tkinter as tk
win=tk.Tk()
txt2=tk.Text(win, height=12, width=50)
win.title('python')
txt2.pack()
win.mainloop()
```