# How to avoid multiple instances of a program?

Tags: python, instance

I need to find a right way to prevent two running instances of my (Python) program.
I am currently using the following method.

On Windows,

```
os.popen('wmic process get caption,processid | findstr `programname.exe`')
```

On Linux,

```
os.popen('ps x | grep `programname`')
```

It seems to work fine for now. Is this method correct?
Can someone suggest to me a better way?

**edit:** Thanks for the reply guys,
Is anything wrong with the above methods?
I tried the pid file way for linux. What if the pid file gets deleted somehow?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the [python-single-instance-of-program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program) question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensuring-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux#221159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous ways:

1. have an "instance file" in /var/run or similar  (cross-platform)
2. use a fixed socket (cross-platform)
3. use DBus to register a name (linux)

What you need is a service (external to your application) that manages a namespace where unique ids are available & enforced.

Answer (score 2):

on Linux, I used to write a pidfile, roughly:

```
if (pidfile already exists)
    read pidfile content
    if (/proc/<pid>/exec == my executable)
        already running, exit
    else
        it´s a stale pidfile, delete it
write my own pid to pidfile
start the 'real' work
```

lately, i´ve heard of the [flock(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) tool.  it´s easier to use in bash scripts:

```
( flock -n 200 || exit
    # ... commands executed under lock ...
) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

and not too hard to use from 'real' programming languages, just open a file and try to get a [flock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) on it.

Answer (score 1):

For linux, see the answer from jldupont.
For windows, use the CreateMutex-method, to create a named mutex. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686927%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This question is about Python, but that link seems to be all about C++ and so isn't relevant. Or am I missing something?