# Making a python script only be able to run once at a time

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: single instance of program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program)

I am looking to make a python script be unique in the sense that it can only run once at a time. For example if I run the script and open another session of the same script a second time and the first session is still running, then the second session will just exit and do nothing. Anyone knows how I could implement this?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380870/python-single-instance-of-program http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensuring-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900979/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-a-program

Answer (score 1):

Never written python before, but this is what I've just implemented in mycheckpoint, to prevent it being started twice or more by crond:

```
import os
import sys
import fcntl
fh=0
def run_once():
    global fh
    fh=open(os.path.realpath(__file__),'r')
    try:
        fcntl.flock(fh,fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except:
        os._exit(0)

run_once()
```

Answer (score 0):

One poor man's solution is to use a file based lock. If you open a file using os.open(), there is a flag that allows an exclusive lock on the file. See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-flag-constants) for reference.