# Preventing creation of multiple GUI instances

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am creating a desktop application for windows using python. I used Tkinter for GUI. My code involves triggering GUI whenever I execute it. 
My requirement is that at any given point of time I should have only a single instance of the GUI running. Can i set some parameter which blocks creation of new instances in Tkinter?

Please suggest some options for the same.

Comment: Would a new instance be created from inside the process, or would it be launched externally as a new process? For the former, the class variable solution would work.

Answer (score 2):

What type of behaviour do you want if someone tries to generate a GUI when one is already running?
Basically what you can do is add a `num_instances` attribute to your class which will be incremented each time an instance is created, then decremented in your class's `__del__` method. You can then check, either in `__init__` or `__new__` depending on the behaviour you want.

```
class GUI:
    num_instances = 0

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.num_instances:
            raise
        self.__class__.num_instances += 1

    def __del__(self):
        self.__class__.num_instances -= 1
```

This is just a draft, so check that it indeed always behave as desired, but it should get you going.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention it but of course you can also look at the [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

**EDIT 2:**
for preventing multiple runs, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900979/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-a-program)

Comment: Yes, if one GUI is already running and a new instance is triggered, still i want only a single GUI to remain. Both are independent. I doubt if this attribute addition will really help.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'both are independent'? Do you mean that the python script could be run several times?
Do you want the OS to have only one instance of your program or is it the python script?

Comment: The python script would run several times and I want the OS to have only one instance of the GUI script which would be called each time the python script runs.

Comment: I edited the answer, also [here](http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2012/08/08/python-allow-only-one-running-instance-of-a-script/) is a page with details about the pid option (which might not be the best one, but I'll let you decide on that)