# python os.fdopen(os.open()) can't be used for writing?

Tags: python

This question has to do with the answer to [Write file with specific permissions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624359/write-file-with-specific-permissions-in-python) for opening a file for writing (in python) with specific permissions.

The code in the answer looks like:

```
with os.fdopen(os.open('foo', os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREAT, 0o644)) as out:
  out.write("hello\n")
```

This code in 2.7.1 (my company does not have 2.7.3 installed) produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IOError: File not open for writing
```

`os.fdopen` has its own mode argument, but setting that doesn't help:

```
>>> with os.fdopen(os.open('foo', os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREAT, 0o644), 'a') as out:
...   out.write("hello\n")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Long story short, I have not been able to figure out how to actually write to a file that has been opened via `os.fdopen` and `os.open`.  Any ideas?  Known bug in 2.7.1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you give `O_APPEND | O_WRONLY` to `os.open`?

Comment: That is indeed the issue, see pilcrow's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must choose one of O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY or O_RDWR as a "basic" mode argument to open().

You did not explicitly do so, so O_RDONLY (zero on many systems) is assumed.  Python's `os.fdopen` sees that you have specified a O_RDONLY *and* O_APPEND, which is a bit silly.  Python complains about this combination with the EINVAL ("Invalid argument") error you see.

(Indeed, if you `strace(1)` your script — I'm assuming Linux here — I suspect you'll see that no "natural" EINVAL is encountered.  Instead, python performs your `os.open()`/`open(2)`, and then checks flags (F_GETFL) on the file descriptor just before raising the exception.)

Comment: Thanks! The error messages when using `os.open` with `os.fdopen` or even `os.write` are very vague (invalid argument, bad fd) when the open mode doesn't match the usage.

Comment: @gowiththeflow: those are the C library's error messages for POSIX/system call errors. You can look them up in `errno(3)`.

Comment: @larsmans, the OP can look them up with `errno.errorcode[]`, too, but I'd agree with the OP that the error message is somewhat vague.  Easy to debug if you already know what the problem is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very funky indeed.

```
os.fdopen(os.open("a1", os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR | os.O_APPEND | os.O_EXCL))
```

works, while

```
os.fdopen(os.open("a1", os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND | os.O_EXCL))
```

raises an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` to the `os.fdopen()`.

So os.fdopen() needs full read/write access to the FD. Unless you do

```
os.fdopen(fd, "w")
```

which than works with write-only files.

Comment: You almost had it....

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

First, `O_APPEND` does not make sense with `O_CREAT` with `O_EXCL`. It will work if the file does not exist, and fail otherwise. So you can *only* append to a file that hasn't been created. Drop either `O_EXCL` or `O_APPEND`.

Second, python's `fdopen` will try to open the file with its default read-only mode. That means that in order to open a file-descriptor as a file-handle object for *writing* or *appending* (so that you can use the `write` method or classes that expect that method). Here's how you can do that as an ugly one-liner:

```
fh=os.fdopen(os.open("a1",os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR | os.O_APPEND ),"w")
```

For clarity:

```
fd=os.open("a1",os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR | os.O_APPEND )
fh=os.fdopen(fd,"w")
```

In my testing, it did not matter if you used `"w"` or `"a"`
h/t: ddalex in his answer.