# Creating and executing a tcsh script from within Python

Tags: python, shell, scripting, vi, csh

I'm attempting to construct and execute a csh script from python.

The code I have produces what looks like a correct script, and `os.system("my_script.csh")` returns '0', but the script doesn't perform the task within it *unless* I go into it manually using vim and re-save it (changing nothing in the script manually - i don't even enter 'insert' mode). What is it that re-saving in vim does that isn't being done in my code, and is it possible to do it?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
grabmeName = '%sgrabme%s.csh'%(dirNames['grabmes'],uniqID)
if not os.path.exists(grabmeName):
    open(grabmeName,'w').close()
    os.chmod(grabmeName,0777)
    with open(grabmeName,'a') as f:
        f.write("#!/bin/csh -f\n")
        f.write("echo 'hello'")
    os.system(grabmeName)
```

Comment: You seem to have an indentation error.  Could you please check your code and make sure that the indention you have here is *exactly* like it is in your code?  I can think of at least one scenario that could lead the the behaviour you see depending on indentation. . .

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo here. Editted.

Comment: why open the file for 'a'ppend and not 'w'rite ?

Comment: I didn't know what effect opening it as 'w' would have on the permissions so decided to play it safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that every line in the shell needs to end with a `\n` in order to be executed, even the last line. You can just add `\n` to the end of the `"echo 'hello'"` string. This is arguably a bug in `csh`, since `bash` and friends don’t have this problem, but if you want to use `csh`, you’ll have to accommodate it.

When you save a text file in vim, it adds a trailing newline to the file if there wasn’t one to begin with. You can verify this by saving a copy of the file beforehand and running `diff` to see what vim changes:

```
$ cat blah-grabme-12.csh 
#!/bin/csh -f
echo 'hello'$ cp blah-grabme-12.csh blah-grabme-12.csh.orig
$ vim blah-grabme-12.csh
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│#!/bin/csh -f                                                                   │
│echo 'hello'                                                                    │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│~                                                                               │
│:wq❚                                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
$ diff -u blah-grabme-12.csh.orig blah-grabme-12.csh.orig
--- blah-grabme-12.csh.orig
+++ blah-grabme-12.csh
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 #!/bin/csh -f
-echo 'hello'
\ No newline at end of file
+echo 'hello'
```

You can turn off this behaviour of vim in your `~/.vimrc` if you'd like. See [`:help 'eol'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'eol') in vim help.

Another potential problem is that `system(filename)` will only work if `filename` is a non-bare path—i.e., has a `/` in it—or if `.` is in the system `$PATH`.

Additionally, by using [`os.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) instead of `open()`, you can set the file permissions at file creation time. Here it might not make a big difference, but in many contexts, creating the file and then changing its permissions results in a [security vulnerability](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2005/Apr/134). [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624359/write-file-with-specific-permissions-in-python) shows how to do that.

---

Putting it all together, you’d get something like this:

```
import os
import os.path

grabmeName = 'blah-grabme-12.csh'

with os.fdopen(os.open(grabmeName, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0700), 'w') as f:
    f.write("#!/bin/csh -f\n")
    f.write("echo 'hello'\n")
os.system(os.path.abspath(grabmeName))
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. How does your version test whether the file exists? I take it that the `os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT`part does this, but your script would run the command even if it has been created before. I need to test whether it exists first as I am running multiple instances of this script and don't want to re-run the command unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it! You can just put the `if not os.path.exists(grabmeName):` line back. I took that out because it made repeated testing of the script annoying: I’d change the Python script, but it would run an old version of the shell script…

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote) it shows many examples.

```
output=`mycmd myarg`
# becomes
output = check_output(["mycmd", "myarg"])
```

As you want to capture the output from the command and not just the return status.

Comment: The script that I actually run is a little more involved (though the problem still occurs with the `echo 'hello'`command in the question) - and I would like to save it as an independently executable file, so that it can be re-run as and when needed.

Comment: I though that you wanted to dynamically create a script, run it and capture it's output. I've had it before where a script has DOS line endings which stops it running which may be why the into vim and out corrects the line endings. Check with `od -c` before and after.

Comment: The script I have saves its output on to the file system, so I don't need the output - I only mentioned it to assert that the script was being executed.