# Make all new directories have 777 permissions

Tags: python, perl, unix, file-permissions

I have a script that, when run, creates a directory inside `/home/test/` and then writes some files in it.  When I run this script, it works fine.  However, when I call it from a perl script with

```
$ret = `/home/..../testscript.py`
```

it doesn't have permissions so it can't create the folder, or can't write inside it after it is created.  It looks like when Python does `open("/home/test/abcde/file1.txt", "w")`, that file has permissions `-rw-r--r--`

What can I do to get around this?  Is there a way to set /home/test to recursively make all subdirectories have global write-access?  Or a better solution maybe?

Comment: How are you making these directories?  You should be able to set the permissions when you create them.

Comment: os.system('chmod -R 777 /home/test')

Comment: os.mkdir("/home/test/abcde")

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5624359/198633)

Comment: What is your `umask` when you run the script?

Comment: The perl script is a CGI file running on my local machine, and it calls the Python script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put:

```
os.umask(0000)
```

in the Python script before it creates the directory. If you can't change the Python script, put:

```
umask(0000)
```

in the Perl script before it calls the Python script.

When a new file or directory is created, the permissions are determined by taking the permissions specified in the call to `creat()` or `mkdir()`, and then masking off the bits that are specified in the `umask`.

Typically, applications specify `0666` or `0777` permissions when they call the function (depending on whether they're creating something that should be executable or not). A common value for `umask` is `022`, which turns off group and world write permissions. If you don't want them turned off, use the above `umask` value to keep the permissions specified in the call.