# Python 3.5 - properties of newly created folders

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following script to create a group of folders.

```
import os
newFolders = ['large', 'list', 'of', 'folder', 'names']
setDirPath = os.getcwd()
for folder in newFolders:
     os.makedirs(os.path.join(setDirPath,folder))
```

This is working great,
Q: Where are the newly created folder's getting their properties from? Do they inherit any sharing/security/custom settings of the folder they reside in? Very new to Python, and want to create 600 client folders for a new project, and would like to avoid as many unintended problems as possible.
[python](/questions/tagged/python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the default properties of newly created folders, but you can specify your own properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756652/6702495

Comment: @ cktang - Still too new the stackoverflow to vote up your response. Thanks, your link, it got me thinking differently about the issue. Not so worried about the inherited attributes, now that I know I can control them!