# How to ensure a single instance of python application on Linux and present the main window when user tries to start it again?

Tags: python, linux, single-instance

I'm building up a pygtk application on linux. I've managed to use the technique described here
[Ensure a single instance of an application in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensuring-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux)
to ensure that only one instance is running.

But what I want now is that when user try to start the application again, the main window of the initial application is brought up instead of any error message.

Comment: There are several techniques described in the page to which you have linked. Which technique are you using?

Comment: I'm using pid file. And I think the solution based on fcntl is using the same idea. Basically I need a way to send a message to the previous process to tell it to bring up the main window.