# I have a linux program that will always run as a single instance

Tags: linux, multiple-instances

I have a linux program that will always run as a single instance given a .conf file listening on a specific port. there's nothing wrong with assigning a totally new and unrelated port but the program will find a way to kill the old one.

is there a way to trick the program into running as different instance on linux using different CPU cores?

Comment: I have tried to rename the program but it doesn't work. it will always kill the original running program even when assigned a different listening port.

Comment: Show us your code, describe what it does instead of working, and perhaps we can help.

Comment: What I have done to do some tricks like this is to scan /proc for the programs name, in order to see, if some instance of it is already running. But this is only a tweak, because I also did not find out, how the proper way is. I would be interested, too. But i found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensuring-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux, so possible duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the second instance in a chroot. its possibly using a pid file in /var or /tmp or its own directory. create a jail location and copy or bind mount all the bin and etc files.