# What is the best way to see if a python process is already running?

Tags: python, daemon

I'm trying to write a script that monitors my python program to see if it is already running.

I started by trying to assign this script to an object:

```
processWatch = os.system("sudo ps afxj | grep quickConversion.py")
if processWatch > 2:  #if more than one is running it won't run.
    while 1:
        "rest of loop"
```

I then tried to monitor the object for more than one instance.

Comment: Is the program running on Linux?

Comment: The program is running on CentOS

Comment: [How about this question, do the answers satisfy you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220525/ensure-a-single-instance-of-an-application-in-linux)

Comment: Try using [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) which provides a nice abstraction for looking at running processes.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you forgot to delete the back ticks in the while loop and on the `"rest of loop"`  in your edit

Answer (score 3):

You may want to pay a look at [psutils](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) to handle processes.

```
import psutil

processWatch = [p.cmdline() for p in psutil.process_iter()].count(['python', 'quickConversion.py'])
if processWatch > 0:
    `while 1: `
        `"rest of loop"`
```

Comment: the psutil library is built for these kinds of tasks and it is cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

There are Linux commands that return a list of processes:

```
if 'your_process' in commands.getoutput('ps -A'):
    print 'Your process in running.'
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the program somewhat "Self-aware" so that if it sees an instance of itself already running it won't run again. I'm using crontabs to run the program every minute so that if it fails it will restart. What could I do to ensure the program won't run if it is already running?

Answer (score -1):

Subprocess's Popen is very useful for this. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
if process.poll() is None:
    print("The process hasn't terminated yet.")
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the OP is talking about processes launched by Python (for which you could use subprocess).

Comment: I'm trying to nest this script within the program that it is monitoring so that when I run the program it will monitor itself at the same time. Can Popen monitor running python programs?

Comment: @Dan:  Are you running one instance of your program or multiple instances?  How are they launched?  By Python or by running them independently?

Comment: I am running one instance. I'm using crontab to run the program so that if it fails it will restart. They are launched by crontab.