# AppConfig.ready() is Running Twice on Django Setup (Using Heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a function that needs to run in the background on one of my web applications.

I implemented a custom AppConfig as shown below:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    run_already = False

    def ready(self):
        from .tasks import update_products
        if "manage.py" not in sys.argv and not self.run_already:
            self.run_already = True
            update_products()
```

However, this command is being executed twice (the update_products() call)

[As stated in the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/)

> In the usual initialization process, the ready method is only called
>   once by Django. But in some corner cases, particularly in tests which
>   are fiddling with installed applications, ready might be called more
>   than once. In that case, either write idempotent methods, or put a
>   flag on your AppConfig classes to prevent re-running code which should
>   be executed exactly one time.

I feel like I am following what the documentation says to do.  What gives?

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @PavelBernshtam, if I remember correctly, it was the gunicorn running multiple threads.  When I changed to waitress for hosting, the problem went away.  I didn't even include the 'run_already=False','and not self.run_already' code at all.

Answer (score 16):

As stated on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814615/how-to-avoid-appconfig-ready-method-running-twice-in-django), if you're running your app, using the `python manage.py runserver` command on Django, your application will run twice: One time to validate your models, and the other one to run your app.

You can change this passing the option `--noreload` to the runserver command.

Answer (score 4):

On heroku, gunicorn is started with more than one gunicorn worker. Set the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to `1`:

```
heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
```

(see [Basic configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration))

Comment: this isn't really a solution when you want multiple threads but need initialization code to run once.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that AppConfig is triggered twice and that causes the Scheduler to get initialized twice with this kind of a setup. Instead, instantiate the scheduler in url.py like this-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/v1/login/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/v1/login/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/v1/', include('rest_registration.api.urls'))
]

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(task.run, trigger='cron', hour=settings.TASK_RUNNER_HOURS, minute=settings.TASK_RUNNER_MINUTES, max_instances=1)
scheduler.start()
```

This way the scheduler only instantiates once. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No flag works on class level. Django is run twice on two separate processes. Class level variables on two separate processes are not visible each other. Use a flag from a database table as in this code (SchedulerUtils is a class written by me with a method go() that starts a backgroud apscheduler scheduler. The model uses a row in the table scheduler_schedulerinfo so you have to insert this row before: "INSERT INTO scheduler_schedulerinfo (started) values (0);"):

```
################################## APPS.PY
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler, BackgroundScheduler
from scheduler.utils import SchedulerUtils

class SchedulerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'scheduler'

    def ready(self):
        startScheduler = True
        pid = os.getpid()

        #check i'm on heroku
        if (os.environ.get("DYNO")):
            # i'm on heroku, here runs twice
            print("[%s] DYNO ENV exists, i'm on heroku" % pid)
            from scheduler.models import SchedulerInfo
            schedInfo = SchedulerInfo.objects.all().first()
            if (schedInfo.started == 0):
                print("[%s] Scheduler not started, starting.... " % pid)
                startScheduler = True
                # set flag to 1
                SchedulerInfo.objects.all().update(started = 1)
            else:
                print("[%s] Scheduler already running, not starting." % pid)
                startScheduler = False # already running
                # reset to 0 for next time
                SchedulerInfo.objects.all().update(started = 0)

        # PRINT FLAG VALUE
        from scheduler.models import SchedulerInfo
        schedInfo = SchedulerInfo.objects.all().first()
        print("[%s] Value of flag schedulerinfo.started: %d" % (pid, schedInfo.started))

        if (startScheduler):
            su = SchedulerUtils()
            su.go()

##################################### MODELS.PY
from django.db import models

class SchedulerInfo(models.Model):
    started = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be checking gunicorn pids as below:

```
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig
import psutil

class SchedulerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'scheduler'

    # I want to start ths scheduler only once,
    # if WEB_CONCURRENCY is set and is greater than 1
    # start the scheduler if the pid of this gunicorn is the same of the
    # maximum pid of all gunicorn processes
    def ready(self):
        startScheduler = True

        #check WEB_CONCURRENCY exists and is more than 1
        web_concurrency = os.environ.get("WEB_CONCURRENCY")
        if (web_concurrency):
            mypid = os.getpid()
            print("[%s] WEB_CONCURRENCY exists and is set to %s" % (mypid, web_concurrency))
            gunicorn_workers = int(web_concurrency)
            if (gunicorn_workers > 1):
                maxPid = self.getMaxRunningGunicornPid()
                if (maxPid == mypid):
                    startScheduler = True
                else:
                    startScheduler = False

        if (startScheduler):
            print("[%s] WILL START SCHEDULER", mypid)
        else:
            print("[%s] WILL NOT START SCHEDULER", mypid)

    def getMaxRunningGunicornPid(self):
        running_pids = psutil.pids()
        maxPid = -1
        for pid in running_pids:
            proc = psutil.Process(pid)
            proc_name = proc.name()
            if (proc_name == "gunicorn"):
                if (maxPid < pid):
                    maxPid = pid
        print("Max Gunicorn PID: %s", maxPid)
        return maxPid
```