# Django: reset a specific field of a model every hour

Tags: django, database, django-models, web-frameworks

I have a field in one of my models in django which I want to be reset every hour.
(i.e. at each o'clock its value becomes zero)

How can I do this task? Can I schedule a function in django?

As you know we can define EVENTs and TRIGGERs in mysql and other database backend. Also I am familiar with signals in django but those can not fit in my needs. (because database event is somewhat outside of django and have problems; with signals although it seems this is impossible!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it's very easy to apply for your problem.

```
import schedule
import time


def job():
    print("I'm working...")


schedule.every().hour.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896618/django-run-a-function-every-x-seconds) there is a thread where it is shown how to execute a task periodically. Then you could add some conditions to fit your scenario.

Comment: thanks. my question is actually a duplicate of your link. but I keep it to guide people that search non-optimum keywords to find the answer!