# How to remove unactivated reservation in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am creating a web app where people can book a football court, the user select the day and the hour, and insert his email and phone number to book the football court.
I don't ask for a sign up, but the user receive an email with an "activation" link to confirm the reservation.
I would write a method or something that every X minutes check for the unactive reservations and delete them if the time has expired.

How can I do it in Django?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for this. Celery is a task queue and supports also task scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [celery](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module to schedule something in Python.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896618/django-run-a-function-every-x-seconds) post for more information about `celery`.

Comment: @Bob, did this answer help you? Please accept it if did! :)