# Getting error on terminating Django server using Threading and Schedule

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading, schedule

I'm trying to use Schedule on the background using threads in my Django application as it was described in [Oz123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897678/1108505), everything works fine without any problem, except when I'm trying to use commands from the terminal (e.g. `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py runserver` ) they will not end and finished until I'm sending `keyboardInterupt`. Then it will give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1388, in _shutdown     
    lock.acquire()
```

*p.s.: for `python manage.py runserver` I have to send `KeyboardInterupt` two times. one for ending the server, then the second one will end the function and raise the mentioned error.*

My application is using one schedule in the background which is happening every hour to check a model for specific changes. So, there is no stop to this schedule and I want to run it until the server is running (forever).

Is there any way to solve this problem? It is so much annoying to press `KeyboardInterupt` (CTRL + C) for ending every command.