# Running an arbitrary Django task along with "runserver" forever

Tags: python, django, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, jobs

For a Django-based server I require the simultaneous running of scripts in a fashion similar to cronjobs. I want to avoid the explicit usage of cronjobs and instead, integrate these periodic tasks to the HTTP server initialization - that is, when I run either `manage.py runserver` or a very similar management command, alongside the HTTP daemon, two other processes start that can perform my tasks periodically.

I already created management commands for these scripts. What are my options?

My best guess is starting two threads either in `AppConfig.ready()` [like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541954/how-to-start-a-background-thread-when-django-server-is-up) or somehow in `manage.py` itself. I'm not entirely sure if it has any caveats, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking this question, I realized my only solution is the initialization of [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and also that I should do it explicitly in either `asgi.py` or `wsgi.py`, depending on my production solution - [runserver management command is not suitable for production.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver)