# Django initialising AppConfig multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-apps

I wanted to use the `ready()` hook in my AppConfig to start django-rq scheduler job. However it does so multiple times, every times I start the server. I imagine that's due to threading however I can't seem to find a suitable workaround. This is my AppConfig:

```py
class AnalyticsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'analytics'

    def ready(self):
        print("Init scheduler")
        
        from analytics.services import save_hits
        scheduler = django_rq.get_scheduler('analytics')
        scheduler.schedule(datetime.utcnow(), save_hits, interval=5)
```

Now when I do `runserver`, `Init scheduler` is displayed 3 times. I've done some digging and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814615/how-to-avoid-appconfig-ready-method-running-twice-in-django) question I started the server with `--noreload` which didn't help (I still got `Init scheduler` x3). I also tried putting

```py
import os

if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
    default_app_config = 'analytics.apps.AnalyticsConfig'
```

in my `__init__.py` however `RUN_MAIN` appears to be `None` every time.

Afterwards I created a `FileLock` class, to skip configuration after the first initialization, which looks like this:

```py
class FileLock:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return os.access(f"{instance.__class__.__name__}.lock", os.F_OK)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, bool):
            raise AttributeError

        if value:
            f = open(f"{instance.__class__.__name__}.lock", 'w+')
            f.close()
        else:
            os.remove(f"{instance.__class__.__name__}.lock")

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        raise AttributeError

class AnalyticsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'analytics'
    locked = FileLock()

    def ready(self):
        from analytics.services import save_hits

        if not self.locked:
            print("Init scheduler")
            scheduler = django_rq.get_scheduler('analytics')
            scheduler.schedule(datetime.utcnow(), save_hits, interval=5)

            self.locked = True
```

This does work, however the lock is not destroyed after the app quits. I tried removing the .lock files in `settings.py` but it also runs multiple times, making this pointless.

My question is: **How can I prevent django from calling ready() multiple times, or how otherwise can I teardown the .lock files after django exits or right after it boots?**

I'm using python 3.8 and django 3.1.5