# Django Python MQTT Subscribe onMessage got executed two times

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, mqtt, mosquitto

I've my Mosquitto MQTT broker and I've created a simple Django APP that subscribes to the topic `$SYS/broker/uptime` like below

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from threading import Thread
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


class MqttClient(Thread):
    def __init__(self, broker, port, timeout, topics):
        super(MqttClient, self).__init__()
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.broker = broker
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.topics = topics
        self.total_messages = 0

    #  run method override from Thread class

    def run(self):
        self.connect_to_broker()

    def connect_to_broker(self):
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port, self.timeout)
        self.client.loop_forever()

    # The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        self.total_messages = self.total_messages + 1
        print(str(msg.payload) + "Total: {}".format(self.total_messages))


    # The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        #  Subscribe to a list of topics using a lock to guarantee that a topic is only subscribed once
        for topic in self.topics:
            client.subscribe(topic)


class AppMqtteConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app_mqtt'

    def ready(self):
        MqttClient("localhost", 1883, 60, ["$SYS/broker/uptime"]).start()
```

For some reason, the `print` statement on the on_message callback got executed two times, at least from what I'm seeing from the console. See screenshot. I can't understand why

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in some instances, particularly in tests, the `ready` method could be called multiple times as suggested in the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/).

As explained on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814615/how-to-avoid-appconfig-ready-method-running-twice-in-django) the issue is resolved with an `if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN'):` before the `ready` method